tanstack/react-router: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
 
I am TypeScript beginner and learning `tanstack/react-router`. However, I couldn't figure out why vscode keeps showing error message `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'` from `createLazyFileRoute` function
// index.lazy.tsx
import { createLazyFileRoute } from "@tanstack/react-router";

function Index() { }

export const Route = createLazyFileRoute("/")({
    component: Index
});

This code snippet was copied from Tanstack Router - Quick Start

Try running tsr watch or tsr generate and it should create a file like this which defines the properties of the interface FileRoutesByPath which createLazyFileRoute uses for its parameter.

Also check this guide out to set up your file based router.

I am using @tanstack/router-plugin so I just need to run npm run dev to generate routeTree.gen.ts. Your comment actually solved my problem but I still haven't figured out why we don't have to explicitly provide parameters to generic function createLazyFileRoute in index.lazy.tsx. Can you write as answer so I am able to accept it?

I'm glad it worked out! From what I understand from the function definition, the function defines a generic parameter to be able to map it to the correct exported route in the relevant file. Notice how the generic type TFilePath which is narrowed/inferred by the argument affects the second generic TRoute which is passed to the returned function. An relation like this which depends on the argument can only be done with generic types, that's probably why they're used

Here's a contrived example.

Tanstack Router generates a file routeTree.gen.ts which declares the interface FileRoutesByPath that createLazyFileRoute uses to map the possible paths. You can either run tsr watch or tsr generate or, if using a bundler plugin, build your project or start a dev server.
Here is a guide on setting up the file based router for different environments.
